# Spring integration sftp is not working after upgrading from 5.2.11 to 5.3.x versions

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-integration-sftp

Getting below error if I am trying to upgrade to higher version of spring-integration-sftp

error occurred in message handler [bean 'org.springframework.integration.sftp.gateway.SftpOutboundGateway#0' for component 'mgetGateway'; defined in: 'class path resource [spring-common.xml]'; from source: ''int-sftp:outbound-gateway' with id='mgetGateway'']; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Failed to execute on session; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to create SFTP Session, failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=/*,

Tried to check the release notes related to finding but not able to get much help. enabled debug logs for this package and got this log.